# How to give access to SQL Server database mail procedures for a Login in a different database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-permissions, database-mail

I'd like to know how to set up permissions within SQL Server to allow my application Login/Role to be able to send email using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`.

I have a database MyDb, a user `MyUser` who is a member of role `AppRole`. I have a stored procedure `myProc` that calls `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`. If I execute `myProc` while logged in as `sa` it all works fine, but if I execute while logged in as `MyUser` I get an error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 1
>   The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

My database does not have TRUSTWORTHY ON, therefore I believe I **can't** use EXECUTE AS to impersonate a different user, e.g. create myProc with EXECUTE AS OWNER... ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx))

Therefore I think I need to make my user(s) also users within msdb, but can I do this at the Role level or do I need to make each of my database users also users in msdb?

The database mail profile that I'm using is set to public, so I don't think this is related to the profile permissions.

Comment: I ended up just creating my users as users within msdb. For simplicity I didn't want to use @Remus Rusanu's suggestion of certificates although in a diff environment that may be a good option. If you have lots of database users it might be possible to use EXECUTE AS to impersonate a single db user and then just give that one user access to msdb - I didn't need to look into that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use EXECUTE AS and sign your procedure and then use the signature certificate to grant EXECUTE permission in `msdb`. See [Call a procedure in another database from an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/), as well as [Signing Procedures with Certificates](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates).

Comment: I should have mentioned: the app is deployed to a range of clients, so signing procedures becomes complicated. But otherwise is a good option.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why is it an issue. Can't the deployment process (the MSI install or Setup) handle the provisioning of the procedure, signing and granting the required permissions?

Comment: In theory yes, in practice I've found the simpler the better when dealing with a large range of DBAs and environments so I'd prefer not to go down the route of certificates etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just grant MyUser public access to MSDB and then grant execute access on the sp_send_dbmail proc to that user. You can add the user by themselves or create a custom role in MSDB and add all the users that need exec access to sp_send_dbmail.

Answer (score 2):

you need give database Role-->databaseusermailuserRole

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) you just need to give the users permission to "the DatabaseMailUser database role in the msdb database".

Comment: And before doing that, make each of my database users also users in msdb?

Comment: You're right, this was not a well thought out response - my apologies.